# C# LINQ .All not working

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I'm trying to compare two lists with LINQ, both these lists are a `List<T>` of the same class but have different values in them.
I've tried various ways like

```
var result = (from r in list1.All
             join r2 in list2 on r.id equals r2.AnotherId
             select r).ToList();
```

However I get the error

```
'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.All<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,bool>)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context
```

I've tried to change my lists to IEnumerable and so on but it didn't do any good.
How do I get .All to work?

Comment: `from r in list1.All` is wrong. Likely it should be just `in list1`. What's the idea behind adding `.All`?

Comment: @Jon I did not make that LINQ got it from another thread. Removing the .All works but I still do not recieve any input, just a empty list even though the values are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you expect `All` to be a field which returns all items from the sequence, however this isn't true. [All()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a method that determines whether all elements of a sequence satisfy a condition.

To join 2 sequences, your code should be simply:

```
var result = (from r in list1
             join r2 in list2 on r.id equals r2.AnotherId
             select r).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, .All is a method, so it needs parenthesis. Secondly, do you know what .All() does? It gives you a boolean whether or not all elements of the list follow the predicate you supply to the method. You should probably just remove the .All in this case.